# Cannot install RabbitMQ: Error in dnf package

Tags: centos, yum, rabbitmq

I have an issue when trying to install RabbitMQ for my OpenStack infrastructure:
I tried to run `dnf -y install centos-release-openstack-xena`.

Everything seems to be OK but when i try to enable my repo and starting an update : `dnf -vv --enablerepo=centos-openstack-xena -y upgrade`

I have this error:

```
CentOS-8 - RabbitMQ 38                                                               171  B/s |  38  B     00:00

Error: Failed to download metadata for repository « centos-rabbitmq-38 » : Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist
```

Here is my file /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Messaging-rabbitmq.repo

```
[centos-rabbitmq-38]
name=CentOS-8 - RabbitMQ 38
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/messaging/$basearch/rabbitmq-38
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=messaging-rabbitmq-38
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-Messaging
```

I tried with the lastest version of CentOS 8 Stream.

If someone could help me it will be great.
Thank you